# libGDX Actor not receiving input

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm learning libGDX, just for fun, and have hit a wall pretty early on. My actor doesn't seem to be receiving touch/mouse input. I have googled extensively and have checked for all the common mistakes (setting inputprocess, setting bounds, setting touchable) but still no luck. Can someone help me out.

**Stage**

```
/* GameStage.java */
public class GameStage extends Stage{

    private Game gameInstance;

    public GameStage(Game gameInstance) {
        super(new ScreenViewport());
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        Tile tile = new Tile(2);
        addActor(tile);    
    }
}
```

**Actor**

```
/* Tile.java */
public class Tile extends Actor{

    public enum Side{
        FRONT,
        BACK
    }
    private int value;
    private Texture backTexture;
    private Texture frontTexture;
    private Side currentSide;

    public Tile(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        backTexture = new Texture("TileBack.png");
        frontTexture = new Texture("Tile " + String.valueOf(value)+".png");
        currentSide = Side.BACK;

        setPosition(0, 0);
        setSize(128, 128);
        setBounds(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

        addListener(new InputListener(){
            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Touch");
                super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        Color color = getColor();
        batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);
        if(currentSide == Side.BACK){
            batch.draw(backTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        else{
            batch.draw(frontTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

What am I missing?? I've also tried implementing touchUp in the stage and returning false and true but no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`touchUp` event is only called if `touchDown` returns `true` (default is `false`). You can fix your code by doing the following:

```
    addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Touch");
            super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        }

        // Add this:
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("down");
            return true;  // Important!
        }
    });
```

On a side note: It's better to use [GDX logger](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Logging) instead of `System.out.println`.